# EWS: Set ItemID->Id when adding a calendar event

Tags: php, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm working on a php connector to ews. For my program, it would be great to be able to set the ItemId->Id to a value I desire.
Is that possible, and if so, how?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether Exchange allows such practices. Maybe additional message headers would give a solution?

**Update**

Regarding to Till's comment and as I presume, answering your problem, the correct answer is NO. The ItemId is read only.

**ItemId - Contains the unique identifier and change key of an item in the Exchange store. This property is read-only.**

More details you may find here - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa580790(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa580790%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

P.